# Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy[GWT]

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I created class like

```
public class FinalizeEvalutionReportPanel extends VerticalPanel{

    //other code...

    public class PopupPanel extends DialogBox
    {
        public PopupPanel() {
            this.setStyleName("gwt-DialogBoxNew");
            this.setText(WorkFlowUtil.getPropertyValue(propertyKeys.showAgreement));
            this.setWidth(StringUtil.getWidthByGivenPercentage(30)+"px");
            this.add(this);
            this.center();
            addHandler();
        }
        private void addHandler() {
            final DialogBox box=this;
            giveFeedbackBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    box.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

I try to call it, from other class on button click.

```
showAgreementBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        new FinalizeEvalutionReportPanel().showPopUp();//this give Java Script error

        }
    });
```

I got this error...

> com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (NS_ERROR_DOM_HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR) @com.google.gwt.dom.client.Node::appendChild(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Node;)([JavaScript object(7280)]): Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the problem is at below line:

```
this.add(this);
```

You can't add a component in itself.